# Promise.all returns empty array

Tags: javascript

I have a array of requests which i'm trying to run with `Promise.all`, but i'm getting no return on the `Promise.all.then()`, not sure why tho...

```
productIdArray.forEach(id => {
  requests.push(rp('https://******br' + '/****/v2/api/*****/' + parametersString + pessoaId + '&idProduto=' + id));
});

Promise.all(requests)
  .then((resultados) => resultados.forEach(resultado => {
    console.log(resultados)
    if (resultado) {
      accounts.push({
        'idProduto': JSON.parse(resultado).content.idProduto,
        'contas': JSON.parse(resultado).content
      });
    }
  })).catch(err => console.log(err));

return accounts;
```

Am I missing something? RP is request-promise lib

Comment: Are you sure you get no results from the `then`, or you get no result from the `return accounts`?!

Comment: Right... `return accounts` will occur before `Promise.all().then()` runs

Comment: `resultados.forEach` returns undefined. Also you are using `Promise.all` inside yet another `productIdArray.forEach` callback. JS wont magically pause the outer function to wait for some inner promise.

Comment: console.log(resultados) prints an empty array, so nothing is being iterated on the then

Comment: No...the promise.all is after the foreach...

Comment: How can it print an empty array if the `console.log` is inside `resultados.forEach`…?!

Comment: @DanielBezerraDeMenezes Still, inner call to `Promise.all` wont pause your outer function. `return accounts;` got executed before `resultados.forEach`

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a Promise from the outer function. Once the part of your function is async entire function is async.

Something like this should do the trick (replace `forEach` w/ `map`)

```
// using map to create an array of pending requests
const requests = productIdArray.map(id => rp('https://******br' + '/****/v2/api/*****/' + parametersString + pessoaId + '&idProduto=' + id));

// returning a promise
return Promise.all(requests)
  .then(resultados => resultados.map(resultado => ({
        'idProduto': JSON.parse(resultado).content.idProduto,
        'contas': JSON.parse(resultado).content
  })).catch(err => console.log(err));
```